# How to allocate pooled resource with ProcessPoolExecutor in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

Each process in my executor needs one of (fungible and mutually exclusive) resource A to run. The resources can be reused in parallel with the processes, and I have the same number of each. How can I do this using inheritance with ProcessPoolExecutor?

I just noticed the context argument of Pool(), is there some way I can use that?

Comment: I have read through the question now 3 times and can't understand it. Can you rephrase it? e.g. what is your is your program doing, why do you use multiprocessing (and why did you choose it over multithreading), what are these resources, would you use them concurrently (e.g. all processes can potentially use all resources at the same time) are all processes reading/writing to these resources or is it reading only etc.

Comment: Sure, sorry about that. I have a pool of multiprocessing.Pipe ends, and each process needs 16 of them to form its own Pipe pool. Each process will run a thread pool of size 16, and each thread takes a pipe and uses it to do a one send-block-receive cycle to a globally shared process which keeps the other ends of all the pipes. The shared worker is a GPU (high latency and high bandwidth) so I found that multithreading was limited by the GIL/CPU. I'm not sure how this is relevant to my question of coupling a resource with a processpoolexecutor though?

Comment: can you please revise this into your question? And can you share a minimal example of what you already have? In this narrated form it's hard to understand.